# Auto align/rotate scanned images in Photoshop?

Tags: rotate, adobe-photoshop, scanning, psd

Is there a way to automatically rotate/align scanned images so they are perfect 90 degrees.

For instance, you scan an image it's slightly crooked, like 88 degrees but the image is rectangular, so you have to modify it manually. Does Photoshop have inherent intelligence to auto-correct? Snap to perfect 90 degree fit?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this will actually be very difficult to achieve because unless you are taking photographs of static objects where very little changes (for example in a Photo Tent) the images you will then ultimately be scanning will be too varied to apply any sort of firm rules of how they should be aligned.

However, there is a sort of Macro / Action function in Photoshop that will allow you to perform an automated task. This may help in some way.

Check out:

> http://www.websitetemplatedesign.com/oscommerce_tutorials/tutorial_260.shtml

Comment: I just discovered it - It shares space with the eyedropper. Tape Measure. You drag a line with it parallel to your 'skewed' line. Then choose canvas rotate/arbitrary and it automatically calculates the distance to rotate to make the image straight.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Use the ruler tool, then choose Rotate Image... Arbitrary.  The correct rotation will automatically be entered.

Got this from: http://graphicssoft.about.com/cs/photoshop/qt/straighten.htm

Answer (score 0):

Intelligent auto-correction may not be as versatile as you wish in Photoshop however you have **Photomerge** ! Although it's pretty tough if you are doing it for the first time, you'll soon get hang of it. This PDF explains it in great detail : http://www.photoshopforphotographers.com/pscs3/download/sample-05.pdf .

Another brilliant resource that you might wanna take a peek at is: http://www.kirupa.com/motiongraphics/align.htm
I think the PDF will be more than helpful to you. It'll even explain to you the concepts in great detail ! Hope I helped.